# Can craft omit default locales from generated paths?

Tags: entries, routes

My bilingual site works fine, but it is not optimal from a url and SEO perspective because Craft is outputting duplicate content on different paths.

My default locale is `en` and the secondary locale is `cy`, this means many English pages can be reached by omitting the local from the path (which is the behaviour I want).

The problem is that certain pages craft generates via the `{{ entry.url }}` parameter contains the locale in the path even for the default one. i.e., Craft is spitting out paths like `http://mysite.com/en/section/entry-title` when I'd prefer it to be `http://mysite.com/section/entry-title`. It's actually accessible from both URLs, which is a bad thing for SEO. I only want the locale parameter added into the path when it's actually needed (i.e., for when we switch to cy).

Is this possible? If not, is there a work-around?

Comment: Do you have a folder `en/` in your root directory, Matt?

Comment: Did you double check that section's entry URL format?

Comment: Good to hear that removing the `en/` folder did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config file you will want to define the locales such that `en` points to the root directory.

```
'siteUrl' => array(
    'en' => 'http://craft.dev/',
    'cy' => 'http://craft.dev/cy/'
 ),
```

And your public `html` folder should not include an 'en' folder:

```
/craft
/html
    /cy
        /.htaccess
        /index.php
    /.htaccess
    /index.php
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks - I'd tried this before but neglected to remove the /en directory!